# Running a server MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cordova

I am trying to add a login/register system to my project (phonegap project) so I am following [this](http://jorgeramon.me/2014/using-mongodb-and-mongoose-for-user-registration-login-and-logout-in-a-mobile-application/) guide trying to understand how to work in a server side. However I don't really get how to get the system working, nothing in the guide mentions how to setup&run the server so I am kind of stuck.

Can someone please explain to me how do I run the server with the MongoDB,Mongoose and node so that my login database would work? perhaps you can also suggest easier methods I would be glad to hear (I saw something about SQL maybe?)

Thank you :)

Comment: Please mention the OS you are using? Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: Have you read the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/installation/)?

Comment: @monotheist running windows

Comment: Please go to nodejs and mongodb site and download the windows binary and install them

Comment: @monotheist I did :O

Comment: @markus w Mahlberg I did. Didn't find something that is connected to mongoose

Comment: @itai Well, you could first set up MongoDB. Then Node. Then you could show us some effort in what you did try yourself.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg so I followed the doc:https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/
and at the stage of "Install the MongoDB service." I didn't quite get how to run the "--install" and the "--config" commands.
I ran mongod and mongo at my cmd, after that I typed what they wrote and it gives my a "syntaxerror".

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg help please

Comment: @itai You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful. Please document exactly what you did, and add it to your question by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34838745/edit). So please add the relevant information and I might be able.